# Stranded reefs after the Zanclean flood?

Tags: zanclean, reefs, messinian, stranded

When the Zanclean flood filled the Mediterranean after the Messinian Salinity Crisis then sea levels around the world would have dropped leaving many stranded reefs and beaches.

Are there any instances of these stranded reefs and beaches around the world?

Also the sudden drop in sea level would have left reef building communities high and dry with no means to reproduce except any larvae that happened to be floating in the sea at the time of the flood. Is there any sign of a sudden catastrophe in reef building ecosystems?